# PHP str_replace issues

Tags: php, imap, str-replace, gmail-imap

I have 2 things I am trying to do here but I am miserably failing and I have tried everything so I don't know the reason.

1. I am trying to use `str_replace` to remove the copyright, but the copyright signature of the email is appearing.
2. For some reason, at random spots in the message, it's entering numbers. I am really confused why this is happening. Below is the PHP code and how the HTML output looks.

**** NEW Output:****
I added the qprint and now I get:
[image]

**Output:**
[image: Example]

**Code:**

```
<?php

/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'username@gmail.com';
$password = 'Password';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if ($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach ($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number, 0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 2);
        $DateFormatted = str_replace("-0500", "", $overview[0] -> date);

        /* output the email header information */
        $output .= '<span class="msg_subject">' . $overview[0] -> subject . '</span> | ';
        $output .= '<span class="msg_date"> ' . $DateFormatted . '</span><br />';

        $bodyFormatted = str_replace("This e-mail (and attachment(s)) is confidential, proprietary, may be subject to copyright and legal privilege and no related rights are waived. If you are not the intended recipient or its agent, any review, dissemination, distribution or copying of this e-mail or any of its content is strictly prohibited and may be unlawful. All messages may be monitored as permitted by applicable law and regulations and our policies to protect our business. E-mails are not secure and you are deemed to have accepted any risk if you communicate with us by e-mail. If received in error, please notify us immediately and delete the e-mail (and any attachments) from any computer or any storage medium without printing a copy.

Ce courriel (ainsi que ses pièces jointes) est confidentiel, exclusif, et peut faire l’objet de droit d’auteur et de privilège juridique; aucun droit connexe n’est exclu. Si vous n’êtes pas le destinataire visé ou son représentant, toute étude, diffusion, transmission ou copie de ce courriel en tout ou en partie, est strictement interdite et peut être illégale. Tous les messages peuvent être surveillés, selon les lois et règlements applicables et les politiques de protection de notre entreprise. Les courriels ne sont pas sécurisés et vous êtes réputés avoir accepté tous les risques qui y sont liés si vous choisissez de communiquer avec nous par ce moyen. Si vous avez reçu ce message par erreur, veuillez nous en aviser immédiatement et supprimer ce courriel (ainsi que toutes ses pièces jointes) de tout ordinateur ou support de données sans en imprimer une copie.", "", $message);
        /* output the email body */
        $output .= '<span class="msg_body">' . $bodyFormatted . '</span><br /><br />';

    }

    echo $output;
}

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

Comment: The 'random strings' seem to be encoded values. They are not random, but are encoded versions of `'`, `á`, and other accent letters.

Comment: its adding the numbers in places where there isnt even accent letters. It takes certain spaces and replaces them with these numbers..

Comment: for example, original email: Please be advised that the Wolfedale/Montreal data centers (SDE) will be undergoing network maintenance on Dec 6th/7th (Wolfedale) and Dec 12th/13th (Montreal). During this maintenance, no downtime is expected. SCOPE: Emergency network maintenance is required due to an issue discovered on affected routers. IMPACT: All hosted websites on the  Media infrastructure, including but not limited to (possible upcoming migrations):

Comment: Just a quick ethics question here:  Why are you removing the copyright?  Is that not immoral, if not downright illegal?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which format the email is coming across as, but it looks like you need to use `imap_qprint($message);` to get the message in the correct format, then do `str_replace('&copy;','',$bodyFormatted);` because it should be in HTML.

The random numbers are from not using imap_qprint().  You have 8bit strings inside your message that need to be converted.

Here's the modified code:

```
    /* get information specific to this email */
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number, 0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 2);
    $message = imap_qprint($message);
    $DateFormatted = str_replace("-0500", "", $overview[0] -> date);

    /* output the email header information */
    $output .= '<span class="msg_subject">' . $overview[0] -> subject . '</span> | ';
    $output .= '<span class="msg_date"> ' . $DateFormatted . '</span><br />';

    $string = "you should get the HTML and put it in there, I'm sure there are things like &nbsp; and other html chars that it's not finding";
    $bodyFormatted = str_replace($string, "", $message);
    /* output the email body */
    $output .= '<span class="msg_body">' . $bodyFormatted . '</span><br /><br />';
```

Comment: Can you please edit and paste the code snippet I am a little bit confused. When a user emails in to me, their signature code contains copyright signature etc and so its showing that on the html.

you say str_replace('&copy;','',$bodyFormatted); but what is &copy

Comment: &copy; is the HTML-encoded version of the `©` sign. I don't see how this fixes your HTML-issues however.

Comment: I would like to remove that whole copy right paragraph..Dont want it displayed when I echo out the html. What should I be editing in my code :S?

Comment: I tried your new code, it now shows a bunch of "?" but still not replacing the copyright message...What should I put in str_replace in order for it to replace the signature?? Like you said there are probably some characters its not seeing, how do I find them so I know what to replace?

Comment: @romo I tested it piece by piece and it replaces the english part of the copyright just fine, just the french part screws up :S I dont know what the REAL html of the french part is so str_replace isnt catching it..

Comment: @nadal what is the email charset?  UTF8, ISO-XXXX?  You might want to try imap_utf8() instead of imap_qprint().  That might help you out there.

Comment: it is charset="ISO-8859-1" what do i do? the signature is utf8 but the body is charset="ISO-8859-1" and I jsut want the body....help please!